# Quickbooks Online : REST API or Java SDK?

Tags: java, rest, clojure, sdk, quickbooks-online

I'm trying to get a clojure program to use the Quickbooks Online API.

After a few days of experimenting, I can construct and sign arbitrary API requests, and get back the answers. This solution seems perfectly acceptable. It's a about a page of code. I can do everything that I can do using the 'API Explorer'.

But I notice that there is a Java SDK to make requests. Like everything Quickbooks related, there seems to be a huge amount of unhelpful documentation and no small sample programs whatsoever.

Is there any benefit to using the Java SDK rather than just using the REST API calls directly?

Would it be worth learning how to use it, and then calling it from Clojure instead of hand-constructing the requests?

And if so, can anyone give me links to small sample programs to make requests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any benefit to using the Java SDK rather than just using the REST API calls directly?

Potentially less work for you, the developer.

The SDKs wrap up the raw JSON/XML responses into objects for you, which may save you some time/code.

Beyond that, no advantage.

> Would it be worth learning how to use it, and then calling it from Clojure instead of hand-constructing the requests?

Entirely subjective.

Do you think/want to save some time/code with the SDK? If so, then learn it.

If you don't think it'll save you a lot of time/you want to roll-it-yourself, then don't learn it.